# Ошибка при удалении символов из строки

Tags: c#, строки

Допустим, есть строка `s`, ее длина - 2 символа. Когда я пишу:

```
s.Remove(0, 1);
```

то удаляется первый символ, все хорошо. Но когда я пишу

```
s.Remove(1, 1);
```

то появляется ошибка:

> `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`: "Индекс и показание счетчика должны указывать на позицию в строке. Имя параметра: count"

Comment: Что то вы путаете.. 2 символа, ваш код и - [результат](https://dotnetfiddle.net/arzCfu)

Comment: 0 знак это как 1-ый элемент строки, соответственно 1 знак это второй элемент строки

Comment: Вы вызываете `s.Remove(1, 1)` после `s.Remove(0, 1)`? Если так, то в строке уже не 2, а 1 символ.

Comment: Если вы посимвольно проверяете сроку, то лучше начните с конца. Так вы не потеряете реальный индекс положения нужного элемента. А если вы просто утрировали задачу, то формируйте список индексов для удаления и удаляйте с большего. Или разбивайте строку в `SortedList<int, char>` и делайте что хотите. Потом склеите строку обратно.

Comment: Попробую со списком сделать. Спасибо!